# how to get all the details in an object when a single detail of the object is given as a reference

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am new to java programming. I have been working on arrays recently. I have written a code that gives the user the items that we have which are stored as objects for each item with details like itemID, Item name, item price, discount on the item etc. in an array. Now, if the user enters the itemID it has to retrieve all the item details corresponding to that ID. How can I retrieve them?

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone will be able to help much without seeing some of your code. At least, as is, the question is unclear to me. This strikes me as a homework problem, consider checking out https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions for ways to help improve reception of your question.

Comment: Normally you have to use a `Map` or an index.  It's not a simple task.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index

Comment: if an array ; you need to find the object that has the same id using loops .

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are storing every one item in one corresponding array.

If you want to search using ID, use a map.

What is a map ?

A map is a mapping between a key and its value. If you give a key, its value can be fetched easily from the map.

So, here ID is the key of the map, array is the value.

Sample code :

> Map map = new HashMap();
>
> for each item, map.put(ID, corresponding array);

So, the mapping would be like

> 1 -> 1's array 
>   2 -> 2's array 
>   3 -> 3's array

If you want to get the array for the ID 3, just do map.get(3) and it will give your array

Answer (score 0):

You have to search the array in a loop for it:

```
/** return null if 'id' is not a itemId of the list, returns the object otherwise **/
public Item getItemById(int id, Item[] all) {
    for(Item i : all)
      if(i.itemId == id)
         return i;
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of the items it would be simple as just itterating throught them and returning when yu gind the item you want:

```
private YourClass searchUsingAttribute(AttributeType searchingValue)
  for(YourClass obj:arrayOfObjects){
     if(obj.attribute.equals(searchingValue)){
       return obj;
     }
  }
  return null;
}
```

of course if your array is sorted then you can use better searching functions (lookup binary search)!